# Showing Type mismatch error on the line ".Caption = Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("cell.Value" & rng).Value"

Tags: vba, excel

---

```
 Workbooks("Nilesh Micro").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 With ActiveSheet

 Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
 Set rng = Range("C1:C10")

 If Not rng Is Nothing Then
 For Each cell In rng.Cells

 If cell.Value = "rng" Then


    QuestionToMessageBox = "Do you want add New Opreator?"

    YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Message Box")

    If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = "6" Then

    Workbooks("B2C_Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Range("M3").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    With Sheets("Dashboard").CheckBoxes.Add(Selection.Left, Selection.Top, Selection.Width, Selection.Height)
    .Caption = Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("cell.Value" & rng).Value

    End With

    ElseIf YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = "7" Then


    Else


 End If
 End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

---

The code is showing Type mismatch error on the line ".Caption =   Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("cell.Value" & rng).Value
". Please some one can help.

Comment: what do you want to do with your code?

Comment: @Nilesh Pawar please load the start of your code and the end, if you indent your code properly, you are missing an `End If` and a `End With` at the end. It's hard to know which variables maybe you declared in the beginning and which ones are not set properly.

Comment: @Nilesh Pawar Second, and more important, you have `With Sheets("Dashboard").CheckBoxes.Add(Selection.Left, Selection.Top, Selection.Width, Selection.Height)` inside your `With ActiveSheet` which refers to "Sheet1" , it's never a good thing to have two `With` statements of 2 different sheets inside each other.

Comment: I have two sheets, 1) Nilesh Micro and 2) B2C Tool, i have lookup value from Nilesh Micro into B2C tool, for those #NA values i want to update in B2C Tool file. And for those #NA value i have updated in Nilesh Micro. This #NA meance NEw operator added in the list. I want to added this new operator to seperate list in B2C tool in Check Box.

Comment: so I guess your code is about the last part of your explanation: what should `rng` represent/contain?

Comment: rng is a Range in Nilesh Micro file.

Comment: so what would you actually want to achieve with 1) `If cell.Value = "rng"` 2) `Range("cell.Value" & rng)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `Set rng = Range("C1:C10")`

and then expect to retrieve a `String`-variable - which you can use as `.Caption` - from

`Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("cell.Value" & rng).Value`?

If I understand your question correctly you might check the following points in your code:

- the `Range()`-method expects either (roughly)

  - a String like `C1:C10`
  - Objects like one `Cell`, two `Cell`s (LeftTop and RightBottom cell), or a `Range`-object that consists of **one** cell
- Now, with your code `.Range("cell.Value" & rng)` you mix up the String `"cell.value"` with your `Range`-object `rng`. Additionally, you typed `"Cell.Value"` (with double quotes) when you likely meant `Cell.Value`
- Additionally: you can only retrieve `Range.Value`, if your `Range`-object consists of **one** `Cell`-object. However, in case of your code `.Range("cell.Value" & rng).Value` its 10 Cells (`C1:C10`)

Comment: We need to clarify where you want to get the `.Caption` from. You try to retrieve it from `C1:C10`. What does this range contain? One String Value? Several? Do you want to a) use the first String in this range as `.Caption`, or b) concatenate them into one string and use that or c) add a checkbox for each String you find in that range? Either way, we need to adjust the way that you retrieve your String from `rng`